# Excel copy paste in multiple sheets at once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Button(Form control) assigned to a macro which returns me to the first sheet.

i want to paste this button to all sheets at once.

Process which i tried and failed

1. Copied the button > then selected all my sheets > paste

excel gives error

2. Used the option to Fill across all worksheet, but nothing happened

Comment: Was the button added via VBA to the original sheet?

Comment: i added the button from Developer tab > Insert > button(form control)

Comment: record a macro of you inserting the button.  Then go into the code and put it into a loop `for each sht in worksheets` ... `Next sht` type deal.